# Binary Search in JS: trying to find a consistent mental model

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary-search

I am grinding LeetCode these days and I encountered the challenge [162. Find Peak Element](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-peak-element/):

> A peak element is an element that is strictly greater than its neighbors.
>
> Given an integer array `nums`, find a peak element, and return its index. If the array contains multiple peaks, return the index to **any of the peaks**.
>
> You may imagine that `nums[-1] = nums[n] = -∞`.
>
> You must write an algorithm that runs in `O(log n)` time.
>
> #### Constraints:
>
> - `1 <= nums.length <= 1000`
> - `-231 <= nums[i] <= 231 - 1`
> - `nums[i] != nums[i + 1]` for all valid `i`

This question is about using binary search to find a peak element in an array.

I know we can think of the array as alternating ascending and descending sequences. Here is my solution

```js
var findPeakElement = function(nums) {
    if(nums.length <= 1) return 0
    let left = 0, right = nums.length - 1
    
    while(left <= right) {
        const mid = left + right >>> 1
        if(nums[mid] > nums[mid + 1]) {
            right = mid - 1
        } else {
            left = mid + 1
        }
    }
    
    
    return left === nums.length ? left - 1 : left
};
```

If the `nums[mid]` is bigger than the next element in the array that we know we are in the descending sub array and the peak element must be lying in the left, and vice versa if then `nums[mid]` is smaller than the next element. So far so good. But what confused me is which index I should return eventually - `left` or `right`? To figure this out I need to go through a bunch of trial and error.

And if I slightly tweek the question to find **the valley element** e.g. `[1, 3, 20, 4, 1, 0]`'s valley elements should be `0`. While I can reason about how we narrow the window but I still cannot seem to figure out which index I should return at the end of the binary search.

Here is my attempt for returning the valley element in the array by mirroring what I did for `findPeakElement`

```js
var findValleyElement = function (nums) {
  if (nums.length <= 1) return 0
  let left = 0,
    right = nums.length - 1

  while (left <= right) {
    const mid = (left + right) >>> 1
    if (nums[mid] > nums[mid + 1]) {
      left = mid + 1
    } else {
      right = mid - 1
    }
  }

  return right
}
```

But this time I cannot use `right` as the returned index. I need to use `left` instead. I cannot seem to think of a consistent way of thinking through this without going through a bunch of examples, which is really not ideal since you still might miss some edge cases.

So my question is, is there some consistent mental model we can adopt when thinking about these binary search problems, specifically which index we should return to satisfy the requirements.

Comment: Binary search only makes sense in **sorted** arrays. If there is a "peak element", the array is not sorted.

Comment: The problem you linked does not mention "binary search" at all.

Comment: @Pointy I guess you are not familiar with Leetcode so it won't say "binary search" in the title or description - you have to figure it out which algorithms or data stcturue you should use to solve the problem.  Go to the discussion section of the problem to see how many binary search solutions you can find

Comment: The question for "some consistent mental model" is quite vague. Does your solution not work?

Comment: @trincot yea it doesn't work. It is buggy.

Comment: a "peak" as described in the problem is simply any particular element whose neighbours are less than the element

Comment: @Joji it doesn't matter whether I'm familiar with Leetcode, the premise of a binary search algorithm is that the list is sorted. If the list isn't sorted, the basic assumptions made with binary search don't hold up, so the algorithm cannot work.

Comment: @Joji also, you **did** say "binary search" in both the question title and the question text.

Comment: @Pointy Can you check the problem description one more time and make sure you understand it? I know binary search can only be applied to arrays that are sorted. IN this question the array IS sorted but it is just alternating between ascending and descending sorting. We CAN apply binary search approach for such an array. You are so dogmatic about it and it makes me wonder if you can only understand binary search from a text book example. Here is the another similar question that can be applied with binary search https://leetcode.com/problems/find-minimum-in-rotated-sorted-array/  go take a look

Comment: @Joji that's not what "sorted" means. If you understood what "binary search" means, it would be obvious to you. The whole point is to skip looking at parts of the list that clearly cannot be the search target. If the list is not sorted, that is impossible.

Comment: @Pointy again, being dogmatic about what sorted means. I know you can tell it is not like `1,2,3` or `3,2,1` but I said it many times it is just alternating between ascending and descending sorting. Go take a look at those two questions and many binary search question on leetcode and read the discussion sections where people post their binary search solutions and yelling to them that they were wrong because they could not apply binary search to a "non-sorted" array (of course your definition of "non-sorted" ).

Comment: "Sorted" means that the elements in the list are in a monotonically increasing or decreasing order by some comparison criterion. This is basic data structures. If you don't understand that, then by all means pursue a "binary search" of an unsorted array and ask more and more questions when it doesn't work.

Comment: @Joji alternating up-and-down-and-up-and-down again is *unsorted*. sure it has some sort of arrangement, but not one that would allow for you to ignore half of the input at each iteration; the behaviour binary search is known for. that is what Pointy is talking about. the other answers here fail for the inputs `[3,2,1,0,4,5,4]` and/or `[4,5,4,0,1,2,3]` as they make improper assumptions about the sorting of the array, which binary search depends upon.

Comment: @Pointy on LeetCode, i see now the [solutions tab](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-peak-element/solution/) contains examples and demonstrations of binary search but the problem description has no such mention. all examples where binary search is used contain either a single peak, or consider the beginning/end of the array a peak, which contradicts the problem's description of a peak: _"A peak element is an element that is strictly greater than its **neighbors**."_ the first/last element only have a single neighbor and therefore cannot be a peak.

Comment: @Mulan, you should also read the rest of the code challenge...

Comment: @Pointy, binary search ***is*** relevant here, even though the array is not sorted. The task here is not to find a *given* value, so it is a different ball game. Binary search has more applications than finding a given value in a sorted list.

Comment: @trincot well maybe I'm missing something, but skipping large portions of the list on each iteration seems sure to miss possible solutions. I suppose that since the requirement is just to find *some* solution, it may work usually, but I would be a little surprised if a test array coudn't be constructed so that the search fails.

Comment: @Pointy, yes, binary search is intended to give only 1 result, and this matches with the requirement to only output one solution. It can be proved that a binary search solution will always work within the given constraints (especially the one that Mulan missed). So I guess you are surprised ;-)

Comment: @trincot thanks _"You may imagine that `nums[-1] = nums[n] = -∞`"_ was ambiguous to me and would've been better communicated with concrete examples, as is commonly the case with these fabricated toy problems. the notation of `nums[-1]` means different things in different languages, but i now understand what it implies. a better problem would come right out and say all inputs will begin and end with `-∞` and avoid having the programmer solve for imaginary out-of-bounds values.

Comment: O(log n) is only possible here as the problem is modified in such a way that first/last elements can be considered peaks despite having a single neighbor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the following condition is true:

```
if(nums[mid] > nums[mid + 1]) {
```

...then it *could* be that `mid` is a solution, maybe even the only one. So that means you shouldn't exclude it from the range, yet with `right = mid - 1` you do exclude it. You should set `right = mid`. To then avoid a potentially endless loop, the loop condition should be `left < right`. This will ensure the loop will always end: the range is guaranteed to become smaller in each iteration<sup>*</sup>

<sub>* Let's for instance assume `left == right + 1` at a certain moment. Then `mid` will become equal to `left` (since the odd bit in the sum is dropped with `>>>`). Now either we do `right = mid` or we do `left = mid + 1`. In either case we get that `left == right`. In all other cases where `left < right`, we get a `mid` that is *strictly* between those two limits, and then surely the range will become smaller.</sub>

Once the loop exits, `left` has become equal to `right`. The only possible index in that range (of 1) is *that* index.

There is now no more need to check whether `left` is `nums.length`, as this cannot happen: with our chosen `while` condition, `left` can never become greater than `right`, ... only equal to it. And since `right` is a valid index, no such out-of-range check is needed.

Also the case of array size 1 does not need special treatment now.

So:

```
var findPeakElement = function(nums) {
    let left = 0,
        right = nums.length - 1;

    while (left < right) {
        const mid = (left + right) >>> 1;
        if (nums[mid] > nums[mid + 1]) {
            right = mid;
        } else {
            left = mid + 1;
        }
    }

    return left;
};
```

### Valleys instead of Peaks

> Here is my attempt for returning the valley element

If you want to find the *valley* element, it will not always work *unless* the following assumption in the question is changed from this:

> You may imagine that `nums[-1] = nums[n] = -∞`

...to this:

> You may imagine that `nums[-1] = nums[n] = ∞`

Once you have that agreed upon, you only have to change the comparison in the above code block from `nums[mid] > nums[mid + 1]` to `nums[mid] < nums[mid + 1]`.

Comment: Using your program, `findPeakElement([3,2,1,0,4,5,4])` returns the correct index `5` for the peak of element `5`. However `findPeakElement([4,5,4,0,1,2,3])` returns index `6` which is the last element, `3`, and incorrect peak as it does not have two lesser neighbors

Comment: @Joji this is exactly what I was referring to in the comments on my post

Comment: @Mulan, please read the Leet Code challenge that the Asker referred to: it states that we may assume that the input array is surrounded by -Infinity values, and so the last element *can* be a peak according to that definition. It is a correct answer.

Comment: Consider an array `a` of 100 elements, all of which are 1, except `a[2]` which is 2.

Comment: The Leet Code challenge also sets as condition that never two consecutive numbers are equal. It should have been included in the question. I have edited the question and added that as a quote from Leet Code now...

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. But how do I find the valley number?

Comment: "the loop condition should be left < right. This will ensure the loop will always end: the range is guaranteed to become smaller in each iteration" this seems really magic to me... if what we have is, in one `if` branch there is `left = mid` and another `if` branch is `right = mid + 1` then having ` while (left < right)` could result into a infinite loop?

Comment: If you want to turn the question into a valley-search, then you *must* also change the requirement about `nums[-1]` and `nums[n]`. They *must* then be imagined as ∞ instead of -∞. Once you have that, then changing the comparisons to do the opposite is enough.

Comment: No, there will not be an infinite loop. The range will become smaller. I added a footnote to my answer about this. Let me know if this clarifies it.

Comment: Good answer, but why not use "-231 <= nums[i] <= 231 - 1"? Call this k and choose your initial 'right' to solve this in min(log n, log k) time.

Comment: @Dave, why not post your idea as an answer ;-) I could add this in my answer, but as it is your contribution... Having said that, max(n) = 1000 and k = 463, so their logs only differ with ... 1 unit.

Comment: Fair enough! I won't bother because my solution would differ for yours by half a line. As for max(n)=1000, just parsing the array is constant time, but finding good solutions for extreme inputs is fun.

Comment: Well, okay, I upvoted yours & posted the dumb constant-time solution.

Answer (score 2):

Since the array is capped at 1000 elements, a simple scan is constant time. If we're imagining that n (size of array) and k (values limited to range -k to +k) can grow, then use trincot's answer, modifying the initial selection of `right` to be capped at min(2k, n) since the max increasing streak is of size 2k+1.

```
def f(arr)
  0.upto(998) do |i|
    return arr[i] if arr[i+1] < arr[i]
  end
  return arr[999] # if we reach this, arr[998] < arr[999] and arr[1000] is -infinity
end
```

Comment: ...and voted ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A *peak* is defined as any element whose neighbours are both less than the element. In the example below, there are are two peak elements, `5` and `4` -

```
        5,
          4,        4,
      3,          3,  3,
    2,      2,  2,      2 ]
[ 1,          1,
```

So we can take three elements off the input, `a`, `b`, and `c` and -

1. if any `a`, `b`, or `c` is null, a valid comparison cannot be made and therefore there is no peak. stop the program
2. otherwise if `a < b` and `b > c`, a peak has been found. output the peak
3. finally drop `a`, and recur on the same input to search for additional peaks

That would look something like this -

```js
function* peaks ([ a, b, c, ...more ]) {
  if (a == null || b == null || c == null) return // 1
  if (a < b && b > c) yield b                     // 2
  yield *peaks([ b, c, ...more ])                 // 3
}

for (const p of peaks([1,2,1,3,4,5,4,2,1,5,6,7,4]))
  console.log("found peak", p)
```

```
found peak 2
found peak 5
found peak 7
```

If you have a significantly large input, which I'm sure LeetCode will give you, handling arrays like this will create an enormous amount of wasteful intermediate values. A better approach would be to use an index, `i` -

```js
function* peaks (t, i = 0) {
  let a = t[i], b = t[i + 1], c = t[i + 2]
  if (a == null || b == null || c == null) return // 1
  if (a < b && b > c) yield b                     // 2
  yield *peaks(t, i + 1)                          // 3
}

for (const p of peaks([1,2,1,3,4,5,4,2,1,5,6,7,4]))
  console.log("found peak", p)
```

```
found peak 2
found peak 5
found peak 7
```

And finally the use of recursion will limit the size of input that this program can handle. We can use a `for` loop to avoid any recursion limits -

```js
function* peaks (t) {
  let a, b, c
  for (let i = 0; i<t.length; i++) {
    a = t[i], b = t[i + 1], c = t[i + 2]
    if (a == null || b == null || c == null) return // 1
    if (a < b && b > c) yield b                     // 2
  }
}

for (const p of peaks([1,2,1,3,4,5,4,2,1,5,6,7,4]))
  console.log("found peak", p)
```

```
found peak 2
found peak 5
found peak 7
```

In the last two example we perform three array lookups per step, `t[i]`, `t[i + 1]`, and `t[i + 2]`. As an optimization we can reduce this to just a single lookup -

```js
function* peaks (t) {
  let a, b, c
  for (let i = 0; i<t.length; i++) {
    a = b, b = c, c = t[i]
    if (a == null || b == null || c == null) continue
    if (a < b && b > c) yield b
  }
}

for (const p of peaks([1,2,1,3,4,5,4,2,1,5,6,7,4]))
  console.log("found peak", p)
```

```
found peak 2
found peak 5
found peak 7
```

This works because our program effectively shifts the elements through `a`, `b`, and `c` in a "leftward" direction. Note the peaks in the `b` column -

| a | b | c | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | null | 1 | 2,1,3,4,5,4,2,1,5,6,7,4 |
| null | 1 | 2 | 1,3,4,5,4,2,1,5,6,7,4 |
| 1 | **2** (peak) | 1 | 3,4,5,4,2,1,5,6,7,4 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 4,5,4,2,1,5,6,7,4 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 5,4,2,1,5,6,7,4 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 4,2,1,5,6,7,4 |
| 4 | **5** (peak) | 4 | 2,1,5,6,7,4 |
| 5 | 4 | 2 | 1,5,6,7,4 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 5,6,7,4 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | 6,7,4 |
| 1 | 5 | 6 | 7,4 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 4 |
| 6 | **7** (peak) | 4 |  |

With our optimised program, we can drop several other unnecessary actions. Index `i` is no longer needed and we can skip having to worry about off-by-one errors caused by `i++` and comparisons of `i<t.length`. Additionally, we can skip the `c == null` check as `c` will always represent an element of the input array -

```js
function* peaks (t) {
  let a, b, c
  for (const v of t) {
    a = b, b = c, c = v
    if (a == null || b == null) continue
    if (a < b && b > c) yield b
  }
}

for (const p of peaks([1,2,1,3,4,5,4,2,1,5,6,7,4]))
  console.log("found peak", p)
```

```
found peak 2
found peak 5
found peak 7
```

If you want to collect all peaks, you can use `Array.from` to convert any iterable into an array -

```js
const allPeaks = peaks([1,2,1,3,4,5,4,2,1,5,6,7,4])
console.log(allPeaks)
```

```js
[2, 5, 7]
```

Generators are a good fit for this kind of problem because they can be paused/canceled at any time, ie after the first peak is found -

```js
const firstPeak (t) {
  for (const p of peaks(t))
    return p                 // <- immediately stops `peaks`
}

firstPeak([1,2,1,3,4,5,4,2,1,5,6,7,4])
```

```js
2
```

If however you want to write `firstPeaks` without using a generator, there's nothing stopping you from doing so. Instead of using `yield` you can simply `return` -

```js
function firstPeak (t) {
  let a, b, c
  for (const v of t) {
    a = b, b = c, c = v
    if (a == null || b == null) continue
    if (a < b && b > c) return b          // <-
  }
}

console.log("first peak", firstPeak([1,2,1,3,4,5,4,2,1,5,6,7,4]))
```

```
first peak 2
```

Comment: fwiw this is a *linear search* program, O(n), and cannot be optimised to *binary search*, O(log n), as the input is neither sorted nor a balanced tree. See also [Big O notation - orders of common functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions)

Comment: hopefully this helps give some insight on how you can build a mental model around this kind of problem. if you have any questions, i'm happy to assist

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, although the question itself didn't ask to output all peaks. Also `o(n)` is not the optimal solution here . I know how to analyze big o. Thanks.

Comment: @Joji maybe you will be surprised to know that generators can be stopped at any time, ie after the first peak is found. These are fundamentals of JavaScript and not necessarily specific to this question. I made an edit that includes a working example. wrt to space/time, if the only peak in the array is at the last element, how would you suggest a more optimal solution? please share!

Comment: lol actually I used generator a ton to walk through ASTs or graphs so I am pretty familiar with it. Thanks for answering.

Comment: the problem with using binary search on this unsorted array means that there are some inputs where it will fail. given `[3,2,1,0,4,5,4]` if you start in the middle at `0` and look to the left you will see a rising edge. if you make the assumption that the peak is to the left, you will ignore the right side which contains the only actual peak, `5`. given `[4,5,4,0,1,2,3]` if you start in the middle at `0` and look to the right, you will see a rising edge. if you assume the peak is to the right, you will make the same mistake.

Comment: "find the peak" is just a toy problem and a "peak" may be defined differently in variations of this problem. if a peak must have two neighbours that are less than it, you simply cannot use binary search. the algorithm can be changed if we know/assume more about the domain. eg, say in some variation we know that there is only one peak, or if we allow the first/last element to be considered a peak, then binary search can useful. if you are seeing mixed suggestions, it may be because you are handling one of these variants.

Comment: however if a peak must have two adjacent lesser neighbors (ie cannot be first/last element), it's similar to finding the maximum/minimum of an unsorted array, O(n). you can repeat a similar exercise to see for yourself: given `[3,2,1,0,1,2,4]` and starting at the middle, `0`, which side should you check for the maximum?

Comment: @Mulan, you write *"...cannot be optimised to binary search,"*: sure it can. Please read the problem description. For your last example, the Leet Code problem -- to which Asker referred -- would accept the first or last index as an answer since `-Infinity` should be assumed at either side of the array. Your code will not pass the Leet Code tests.